# Differences in bin values between cut and geom_histogram R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was looking to plot the location of local minima on a histogram. I used the following code to look at the data and find a local minima:

```
bins = cut(Seurat_obj$nCount_RNA, 
             breaks = seq(0, max(Seurat_obj$nCount_RNA) + dist, by = dist))
  
bin_counts_table = table(bins)
bin_counts = as.vector(bin_counts)
names(bin_counts) = names(bin_counts_table)
print(data.frame(bin_counts))
```

This gives me the following data frame:

[image]

I then used the following code to plot the histogram:

```
  p = ggplot(Seurat_obj@meta.data, aes(x=nCount_RNA)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=dist) +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept=1500), #hardcoded here but I have code to determine this
            color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, max(Seurat_obj$nCount_RNA)+dist, by = 3*dist))
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

Is there some diffrence between cut and geom_histogram that is changing the way the bins are calculated? Why are the minima diffrent?

Comment: `geom_histogram` is probably using different bin boundaries than what you specified with `cut`. What do you get if you set `boundary=0` in `geom_histogram` (while keeping `binwidth=dist`)? Alternatively, you can specify a `breaks` argument (set it equal to the same vector you used for the `breaks` in the `cut` function) instead of the setting `binwidth` and `boundary`.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The breaks were different setting boundary=0 fixed the issue. See @eipi10's comment.

[image]